# how to use cookie to save filterBy in bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Cookie can save sortOrder, sortName, pageNumber, pageList, columns, searchText, filterControl,but can`t save filterBy.

I want to jump to a new page, return to the existing form can retain the results of the filter.

```
<a id="filterBy">filterBy</a>
<table data-toggle="table" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Stars</th>
        <th data-field="status">Forks</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="tr-id-1" class="tr-class-1">
        <td id="td-id-1" class="td-class-1">
            <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table">bootstrap-table</a>
        </td>
        <td>526</td>
        <td>122</td>
        <td>An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-2">
            <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select">multiple-select</a>
        </td>
        <td>288</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
        <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-3">
            <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-show-password">bootstrap-show-password</a>
        </td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-4" class="tr-class-4">
        <td id="td-id-4" class="td-class-4">
            <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/blog">blog</a>
        </td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>my blog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-5" class="tr-class-5">
        <td id="td-id-5" class="td-class-5">
            <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/scutech-redmine">scutech-redmine</a>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Redmine notification tools for chrome extension.</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
var $table = $('table');
$('#filterBy').click(function() {
    $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {
        status: '4'
    });
})
```

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvwzh1991/mow64ndb/),thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the extension adding

`<script src="extensions/cookie/bootstrap-table-cookie.js"></script>`

```
<table 
      data-cookie="true"   <---- here
      data-toggle="table" 
      data-pagination="true" 
      data-search="true" 
      data-filter-control="true" 
      data-show-search-clear-button="true" 
      data-reorderable-columns="true" 
      data-total-rows="true" 
      data-show-footer="true" 
      data-show-toggle="true" 
      data-sortable="true" 
      data-show-columns="true"> 
<thead>
 . . .
<thead>
<tbody>
 . . .
</tbody>
</table>
```

See more information at https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/cookie/